# renv::restore() is nail-bitingly slow

Tags: r, renv

I am trying out the `renv` package for the first time.

I took an existing project I manage with packrat, removed the .Rprofile and the packrat dir (I was happy starting from scratch)

I added a local work repo using options, and then ran renv::init(). This discovered what looks like a complete list of dependencies (138 CRAN packages, 10 work packages, and one github installed package)

I then copied that folder to another comupter, changed RENV_PATHS_SOURCE to something globally available on that system and went to the project directory, started R, it told me it was out of sync and asked me to run status. I did, it looked fine, reported a bunch of lirbaries that needed installing. then I ran renv::restore()

It then correctly listed all the dependencies, and then moves on to install them.

And this is really slow.

I sit here waiting, seeing new tarballs being listed as they are fetched, and it takes, at best, a whole minute to fetch each one. but more typically somewhere in the range 1-2 minutes each.

Which is strange, because they are listed as being downloaded in 0.2-0.7 seconds each. Sniffing network interfaces confirm this. There are bursts of packages coming in for brief moments, with each new tarball listed, which seem like they could match the reported times spent.

R cpu usage fluctuates between 0.0% and 1.0% during all this.

So what is renv doing?

So for a not particularly complicated project, that pulls in 180 packages, I'd be waiting 3 hours just to fetch tarballs? That themselves only should take 0.5 seconds each? This will become a problem. Me personally I'm holding of migrating from packrat until this is solved or understood.

But what is renv doing or waiting for? There is no network activity, no cpu usage, no iowait, as far as I can tell (looking at top output).

Comment: You can also try checkpoint: https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/checkpoint Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer

Comment: After digging in some more, it appears renv doesnt like our local work repository having a path appended to the url.

Is there are a requirement that repositories be top level domains? I'd think not

Comment: I posted an issue with this here: https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/445